# Additional local administrators on Azure AD joined devices is not allowing users who are added to be Local Admins

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have installed several new computers to a client and have Azure AD joined them. They are all windows 10 and were setup out of the box. I added them with the global admin account. In azure I added users the additional local admin in device settings as I need a couple of users to have this access to edit registry and install applications.

**The problem: When that user logs in they have no local admin rights.** I'm not sure what I have done wrong. I have logged them out and back in, I have rejoined the devices and still nothing is working.

Please Help!!

Comment: Users are in the device admin role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In azure I added users the additional local admin in device settings
>   as i need a couple of users to have this access to edit registry and
>   install applications.

To add the additional local admin on aad joined device, the azure ad should be premium, and you also need to manually elevate this user on the device.
To manually elevate a user on a device, you could try the following ways:

- Settings -> Accounts -> Other users by selecting Add a work or school user
- using the command prompt:

  a. If your tenant users are synchronized from on-premises Active Directory, use `net localgroup administrators /add "Contoso\username"`.

  b. If your tenant users are created in Azure AD, use `net localgroup administrators /add "AzureAD\UserUpn"`.

For the details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/assign-local-admin#manually-elevate-a-user-on-a-device).

Comment: why would you need to manually elevate the uses if its already been set in Azure AD? I am glad this user only uses 5 devices and i can touch each of them to manually add, but what if this user needed to access to every computer on the network.. This could be up to to 50 computers.

Comment: I tried this operation in azure, but when I checked the admin group on the joined device, I cannot find the added user, so you also need to manually add the user.